# How to provide a "double prefix argument" programmatically?

Tags: emacs

In some code, I want to set the mark.

The documentation for `set-mark-command` says,

> With C-u C-u as prefix argument, unconditionally set mark where point is.

So how do I call `set-mark-command` in this way?

EDIT: I see I should be using `push-mark` instead, in this particular case.  But the general question of how to provide a double-prefix argument programmatically remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
(set-mark-command '(16))
```

Small explanation to find this info:

1. <kbd>f1 f</kbd> `set-mark-command`
2. jump to definition in `simple.el` from the `*Help*` window.
3. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-M-x</kbd> will call `eval-defun` with a prefix argument, which instruments the code for debugging when the function is called.
4. <kbd>C-u C-u M-x</kbd> `set-mark-command`.
5. You should now be in the debugger. <kbd>e</kbd> `arg` will give `(16)`.

Answer (score 3):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: This is also an excellent answer.  The reference material there is exactly what I was looking for.  I would accept both if I could!

Comment: This answer links to the documentation but does not provide a response. Currently this way of accessing the documentation is unavailable, at least for the Emacs 24.5.1 I am using.

Comment: @atfornes, this info node is definitely included in 24.5.1. There is, however, a discrepancy with the way you need to *type* the node names, so leave out the space between `(elisp)` and the remainder. If you somehow have acquired a version of Emacs which does not include its manuals at all, then you have a deficient installation. The manuals provide crucial information, and the Info format and reader is the best way to read and search them, so you should ensure that you have them available.

Comment: thanks @phils for the comment. Apparently the license of the emacs info files is not free for Debian standards https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/debian-wheezy-where-are-emacs-info-files-4175473062/
Threfore default emacs installations in Debian systems without non-free package repositories miss this info files. installing emacs*-common-non-dfsg from the non-free repositories seams to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's *terrible* for the users :/ I hope that this will be resolved at some point.

Comment: @phils, Despite the link to the documentation, this response should provide the information needed to solve the problem (See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). If you can, please complete the answer with what you think it was useful in the documentation.

Comment: You can find the manual in html form as a fallback option. The URL for the node in question is: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html . I personally don't feel that the meta post applies to instructions to use the in-built Emacs manuals (and I hold to my statement that Emacs without its manuals is a deficient installation), so I shan't quote the whole page. My intent here was to get people reading that node of the manual, which is *all* relevant to the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17186524)

Comment: @TobySpeight +any other reviewers of this answer: Please notice that this answer is _not_ a link to a web page. It is instructions for how to resolve this emacs question within emacs itself. It has meaningful content and is useful. Google could not give me an answer for this, but this answer did. This answer is not subject to link rot -- it can become useless only in the same way that _every_ answer can: emacs may change in the future. I was serious in my first comment that this is an excellent answer. I am defending this answer because I saw you "recommend deletion" for it! I hope it remains!

Comment: @Matt, it's not a link to a *web page*, but it's still a pointer to an answer and not the answer itself.  It's close to saying, "[your answer is in another castle](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)" (but does at least include the info page title).  I think it would be better if it included the relevant answer *as well as* explaining the best way to find such things in the included documentation.

Comment: @TobySpeight: A key difference from the "other castle" analogy is that the "other castle" in this case is the very castle that the question is about. The question asks what to do in emacs, and the answer says what to do in emacs. The answer refers to the same body of documentation as the question itself does. But if you think it would still be useful to also add `(set-mark-command '(16))` to this answer, it can certainly be edited in. I assume the answerer just didn't bother repeating this info since it was already given in the other answer.

Comment: It's more that I'm adamant that my answer is good as-is -- people who are asking questions such as this one *should* read that entire page of the documentation, and they can do so within Emacs, and I've shown them how to do that.  If it was a small excerpt of the page that was relevant then I would have quoted it (so that they didn't need to find the relevant bit themselves), but in general quoting an entire page is *worse* than showing people how to access it inside Emacs, because the documentation inside Emacs (*their* Emacs) is the one which is guaranteed to be relevant to *them*.

Comment: Getting people more familiar with the documentation within Emacs also helps them to solve problems for themselves in the future.  The more often they use the manual, the more likely they will be to think of it in future, so I very regularly point people at the in-built documentation in my Emacs answers.  I firmly believe that this benefits the users to a greater degree than simply quoting from it.  (Although again, I *would* quote from it if it was only a part of the page, and I simply considered that less appropriate in this case.)

Comment: Also, thanks for your comments here, Matt.  I don't want to waste any more of anyone's time, so if there is a genuine insistence that I quote the documentation in this answer then I shall add that in so that everyone can move on (but I stand by my statement that the answer is actually better the way it is).